# How to use analog camera live stream through dvr for face recognization

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on face recognization using `OpenCV` and `python`.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("videoplayback.mp4")
```

At the place of this video link, I want a DVR live stream video link.

Comment: Is there any another way to fetch CCTV live streaming?

Comment: With VideoCapture you can connect to a live stream, you need the link of the stream not the HTML link.

Comment: how to connect with the live stream using VideoCapture?

Comment: you can connect to rtsp streams via their url. If you only have the raw analog camera, you'll need a frame grabber. Depending on your needs you can buy professional ones or simple usb grabbers like the Hauppauge USB Live 2. Then you can in theory again capture them with openCV's VideoCapture by accessing a device id (same as for cameras), but for windows there is a bug in the capturing for such devices which can be fixed easily in OpenCV source code.

Answer (score 1):

You can access through the RTSP protocol, which needs a different syntax depending on the brand of the DVR.

Here is an example for a Hikvision DVR:

```
con = 'rtsp://USER:PASSWORD@IP:PORT/(h264/MPEG-4)/ch(CHANNEL)/(main/sub)/av_stream'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(con)
```

And here an example for a Dahua DVR:

```
con = 'rtsp://IP:PORT/cam/realmonitor?channel=CHANNEL&subtype=ENCODING&authbasic=LOGIN'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(con)
```

Usually the port value is 554